# get contents of url in python

Tags: python, urllib2

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.xyz.com')
html = response.read()
```

IN http://api.xyz.com

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":18,
    "params":{
      "indent":"on",
      "q":"",
      "wt":"json",}},
  "response":{"numFound":7984,"start":0,"maxScore":1.0,"docs":[
      {
       "id":"21",
       "first_name":"anurag"
      },
      {
       "id":"31",
       "first_name":"abhishek"
      }
    ]
}
```

Problem is: this url will return json output. and i want to read that json file but it is showing error: string indices must be integers, not str.

Comment: Please include the code that throws the error, and the full traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the JSON response to a python structure with the [`json` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) (included with Python):

```
import json

import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.xyz.com')
data = json.load(response)  # note, no `.read()`, the library handles that

print data['response']
```